# Merge two CSV columns and match up

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with three major columns I need to infuse.

One of them is a name of the product called "Material" 
One of them is the group name called "Serial"
The final is "Related" which matches the Martial with the Serial

At the moment the CSV will look like the following:
(example, has more fields and different data)

```
Martial | Serial     | Related
ExOne   | GroupOne   | 
ExTwo   | GroupOne   |
ExThree | GroupOne   |
ExFour  | GroupTwo   |
ExFive  | GroupTwo   |
ExSix   | GroupThree |
```

I need to match each martial to each over by the serial but limited to five (and separated by "///"

The example outcome should look like the following:

```
Martial | Serial     | Related
ExOne   | GroupOne   | ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
ExTwo   | GroupOne   | ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
ExThree | GroupOne   | ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
ExFour  | GroupTwo   | ExFour///ExFive 
ExFive  | GroupTwo   | ExFour///ExFive
ExSix   | GroupThree | ExSix
```

This is my first attempt at Python and the code that i've tried at the moment is only touching on what I said. The way I'm building the code is bit by bit, the first bit (aim) is to match the serial groups and list all martial items under, for example:

```
GroupOne
ExOne
ExTwo
ExThree

GroupTwo
ExFour
ExFive

GroupSix
ExSix
```

Then from there I can make cases and combine by factors (if more then 5 ect)

```
import csv
import sys  

with open('EGLOINDOORCSV.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    Materials = []
    Serials = []
    for row in readCSV:
        Material = row[0]
        Serial = row[4]

        Materials.append(Material)
        Serials.append(Serial)

        if Serial == Serial:
            print(Serial)
            print(Material, end = "///")
            print("\n")
            break 

    print("Done")
```

Comment: Please note: This is my first ever Python attempt

Comment: If it's possible in standard Python my aim is to try that as I'm still on the basics

Comment: Yeah, i'm not surprised haha

Comment: The thing is... as soon as you learn pandas there is really no reason to keep doing it without it. It becomes harder to read, understand and edit. I can have a look at it without pandas.

Comment: I will attempt pandas if I need to edit more CSV's

Comment: Python without pandas for handling tables is a pain in the ass. You should know some libraries like collections and itertools and be familiar with comprehensions and string formatting to write readable code. Trust me, if you aim to use Python for manipulating table data. Learn pandas!

Comment: I agree with @AntonvBR, if you have few data and you are looking for a pythonistic way, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080325/842935 approach. If this is for a professional goal or you are using a lot of data, then, read AntonvBR approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to read the CSV twice. In the first pass, I gather related information and in the second, output:

```
import csv

# Pass 1: gather related materials
with open('EGLOINDOORCSV.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    related = {}
    for row in reader:
        material = row[0]
        serial = row[1]
        related.setdefault(serial, set()).add(material)
# print(related)  # for debugging

# Pass 2: print
with open('EGLOINDOORCSV.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        material = row[0]
        serial = row[1]
        print('%s | %s | %s' % (material, serial, '///'.join(sorted(related[serial]))))
```

Output:

```
ExOne | GroupOne | ExOne///ExThree///ExTwo
ExTwo | GroupOne | ExOne///ExThree///ExTwo
ExThree | GroupOne | ExOne///ExThree///ExTwo
ExFour | GroupTwo | ExFive///ExFour
ExFive | GroupTwo | ExFive///ExFour
ExSix | GroupThree | ExSix
```

## Notes

- I assume your CSV file does not have a header. If you do, you will need to skip it:

  ```
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  next(reader)  # Skip the header, then move on
  ```
- Based on the CSV you supplied, I assigned `row[0]` to `material`, please adjust the index number to match your file

## About the `related` dictionary

This dictionary is where I keep the relations, it looks like this:

```
{
    "GroupTwo": set(["ExFour", "ExFive"]),
    "GroupOne": set(["ExOne", "ExThree", "ExTwo"]),
    "GroupThree": set(["ExSix"])
}
```

In my code, the statement:

```
    related.setdefault(serial, set()).add(material)
```

is a shorthand for:

```
    if serial not in related:
        related[serial] = set()
    related[serial].add(material)
```

Comment: Note: I could have read the CSV once and do processing, but if the file is large, keeping all the rows in memory might not be a good idea. That is why I chose to read it twice and not hogging the memory.

Comment: Which is ideal as the RAM stick in my pc are slow and low. I also I thought I would check the short hand but doesn't appear to function

Answer (score 2):

First let's recreate a sample file:

```
data = '''\
Martial|Serial|Related
ExOne|GroupOne|
ExTwo|GroupOne|
ExThree|GroupOne|
ExFour|GroupTwo|
ExFive|GroupTwo|
ExSix|GroupThree|'''

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Now the actual code using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (Pandas comes together with the Anaconda package). Use `pip install pandas` to install it without anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')

df['Related'] = df['Serial'].map(df.groupby('Serial')['Martial']
                .apply(lambda x: '///'.join(x)))

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Returns:

```
   Martial      Serial                  Related
0    ExOne    GroupOne  ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
1    ExTwo    GroupOne  ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
2  ExThree    GroupOne  ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree
3   ExFour    GroupTwo          ExFour///ExFive
4   ExFive    GroupTwo          ExFour///ExFive
5    ExSix  GroupThree                    ExSix
```

Comment: hi @antonvBR. Nice and clean solution with pandas, remember to include in your answer how to install and import it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach using inbox [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), you don't need to install any extra package.  Then this is how to write it in a **pythonistic way** also using **dictionary and list comprehension**.

Step by step approach:

```
#reading all file at once
import csv
with open('EGLOINDOORCSV.csv') as csvfile:
   l=[r for r in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=r',')][1:] #skip header

#itertools requires sorted data. Sorting by second field.
key=lambda x: x[1]
l = sorted( l, key = key)

#grouping to an aux dictionary
from itertools import groupby
d={ k: "///".join( x[0] for x in g) for k,g in groupby( l, key) }

#updating third column from aux dictionary
for x in l: 
    x[2]=d[x[1]]
```

Et voilà!

```
#this is the content of l, ready to go back to a new csv
[
 ['ExOne', 'GroupOne', 'ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree'],
 ['ExTwo', 'GroupOne', 'ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree'],
 ['ExThree', 'GroupOne', 'ExOne///ExTwo///ExThree'],
 ['ExSix', 'GroupThree', 'ExSix'],
 ['ExFour', 'GroupTwo', 'ExFour///ExFive'],
 ['ExFive', 'GroupTwo', 'ExFour///ExFive'],
]
```

**Disclaimer**: *This is a vanilla solution, all in the box, but remember, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is your friend handling data, take in mind to install it and move to a pandas solution if you need to manage lots of data.*

**Raw data**

```
$cat EGLOINDOORCSV.csv 
Martial,Serial,Related
ExOne,GroupOne,
ExTwo,GroupOne,
ExThree,GroupOne,
ExFour,GroupTwo,
ExFive,GroupTwo,
ExSix,GroupThree,
```

Comment: After I get use to Python I will more onto more libraries like Pandas.

Comment: I'm getting the error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This is because delimiter, refresh page, I changed it to your delimiter.

Comment: If the file is large and/or memory is limited, this code does not perform well. For example, `[r for r in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=r',')]` creates one large list of rows in memory which is bad enough. Then, `[:1]` creates another list. So for a brief moment, we have 2 large lists in memory before the old one was sent to the garbage collector. The `sorted` call is another: for a moment, we have two lists in memory before the garbage collector can perform its job.

Comment: I wrote it in a pythonistic way. @HaiVu, read disclaimer, for a big dataset just use Pandas. Please HaiVu, don't try to lie people, your approach is a pain for a big file.